# Setting XMLHttpRequest.responseType forbidden all of a sudden?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I've been using synchronous XMLHttpRequest with responseType set to "arraybuffer" for quite a while to load a binary file and wait until it is loaded. Today, I got this error:
"Die Verwendung des responseType-Attributes von XMLHttpRequest wird im synchronen Modus im window-Kontekt nicht mehr unterstützt."
which roughly translates to 
"Usage of responseType for XMLHttpRequest in synchronous mode in window-context(?) no longer supported."

Does anyone know how to fix this? I realy don't want to use an asynchronous request for something like this.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, false);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
```

Works fine in chrome.

Comment: You can do binary synchronous XHR's in Web Workers...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is correct behaviour, as defined in the [Specification of XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-responsetype-attribute):

> When set: throws an [`"InvalidAccessError"`](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#invalidaccesserror) exception if the [**synchronous**
>   flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#synchronous-flag) is set and there is an associated [XMLHttpRequest document](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#xmlhttprequest-document).

The `responseType` property cannot be set when the `XMLHttpRequest` is not async, that is, synchronous. Setting the third parameter of `open` to `false` causes the request to be **synchronous**.

Comment: Sounds weird to me that something like that is supposed to throw an exception. But thanks for pointing me to the specification.

Comment: @Markus The point is that you shouldn't be writing new code that uses sync XHR.  Removing it altogether would break existing sites, but browsers and the spec are trying to restrict its use in new code so that new code actually does the right thing and uses async XHR.

Comment: crippling the platform for no reason, the hate is mutual

Answer (score 12):

#### Workaround

For the casual reader, if you still need the synchronous behavior, you can download your content as string and then convert it to byte data

**NOTA:**
*This workaround assumes the original `request.response` is an `ASCII` text.

If this assumption doesn't fit your specific use case please see [jBinary](https://github.com/jDataView/jBinary).*

I convert it to an `ArrayBuffer`.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, false);
request.send(null);

var data;
if (request.status === 200) {
    data = stringToArrayBuffer(request.response);
} else {
    alert('Something bad happen!\n(' + request.status + ') ' + request.statusText);
}

// ...

function stringToArrayBuffer(str) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
    var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);

    for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return buf;
}
```

#### More reading

- [jBinary](https://github.com/jDataView/jBinary): High-level API for working with binary data in Javascript.
- [Sending and Receiving Binary Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data): Binary data handling with vanilla Javascript. (*Source:* Mozilla Developer Network)

#### References

- [Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11058858/363573)
- Renato Mangini's original function [str2ab](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String)
- [Easier ArrayBuffer <-> String conversion with the Encoding API](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/08/Easier-ArrayBuffer---String-conversion-with-the-Encoding-API) (Jeff Posnik)

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the original binary (non-ascii) binary data exactly?

Comment: @TamasHegedus To answer your question, I have updated my post with a **More reading** section.

Comment: I am suspicious about the binary-text-binary conversion not yielding the original bytes

Comment: @TamasHegedus The workaround presented here works *only* with the assumption the original bytes are encoded in ASCII.

Answer (score 9):

As it's not possible to set `responseType = 'arraybuffer'` in sync mode, receiving string and converting to bytes is a solution, but as Stephan said, your data should be an ascii text. You will receive wrong value (253) instead of all bytes above 127.

But setting `mime-type` and charset to `x-user-defined` might be a solution:

Here server send 10 bytes from 125 to 134:

```js
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
request.open('GET', url, false);
request.send();
Uint8Array.from(request.response, c => c.charCodeAt(0));
> Uint8Array(10) [125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134]
```

without setting mime-type it's like this:

```js
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, false);
request.send();
Uint8Array.from(request.response, c => c.charCodeAt(0));
> Uint8Array(10) [125, 126, 127, 253, 253, 253, 253, 253, 253, 253]
```

Comment: This answer is best for me!
using 'overrideMimeType' is a solution

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky enough to have control over the entry point of the whole page, consider wrapping the whole thing with an `async` function and using `await` to block on problematic asynchronous code. Might not work with all use cases though.

```
(async function () {
    await problem_function_1();
    await problem_function_2();
    ... normal page logic pasted here ...
})();
```

Wrap async code that is not a promise with a `Promise` (so that await works as expected), and call the resolve function manually in whatever constitutes a "success callback". Do the same for reject if possible.