# set responseType of a HttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I would like to do this :

```
function loadSound(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    // Decode asynchronously
    request.onload = function() {
        context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
            sound= buffer;
        }, onError);
    }
    request.send();
}
```

But I got this error :

> Uncaught InvalidAccessError: Failed to set the 'responseType' property on 'XMLHttpRequest': The response type cannot be changed for synchronous requests made from a document.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something the specifications define:

> Note: Starting with Gecko 11.0 (Firefox 11.0 / Thunderbird 11.0 / SeaMonkey 2.8), as well as WebKit build 528, these browsers no longer let you use the responseType attribute when performing synchronous requests. Attempting to do so throws an NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_ACCESS_ERR exception. This change has been proposed to the W3C for standardization.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Yes I saw that, but now how do you do that? ^^

Comment: Download as string and convert it. I guess it has been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855127/setting-xmlhttprequest-responsetype-forbidden-all-of-a-sudden