# why xhr cannot set response type when async is false

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.responseType = 'json';

xhr.open('GET', '/api/album/category', false);
```

//ERROR: VM829:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Synchronous requests from a document must not set a response type.at :1:5(anonymous function) @ VM829:1

why xhr cannot set response type when async is false?????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9855305/2545680

Comment: Because SJAX is bad and shouldn't be used anyway. It's limited to the most simple use cases, and does not support response types, CORS, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the response type when the synchronous flag is set (i.e, asynch is false) . It will throw an "InvalidAccessError" exception . Refer https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-responsetype-attribute