# How to add headers to the request url in <img> src?

Tags: html, http

Example:

```
<img src='https://example.com/getImage?q=img_ref' />
```

And the `https://example.com/getImage` requires us to send some specified headers to make the request valid. Is it possible, or do I have to use ajax for this?

Comment: @alex23: thanks! I was just wondering if it's possible with some hidden HTML5 feature. Seems like not.

Comment: Were you able go get this working?  I have similar issue that I need to solve.

Comment: @DrChanimal: no, it's not possible. I ended up using ajax since our back-end supported base64 responses.

Comment: @shershams after using ajax, how do you set it as the `src` attribute of the `img` tag?

Comment: @mehulkar: You would have to set an id/class to img tag, and then fill the src with base64 string with "data:image/png;base64," prefixed using Javascript

Comment: @shershams how do I convert the downloaded file to a base64 string?

Comment: @mehulkar: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370943/retrieving-binary-file-content-using-javascript-base64-encode-it-and-reverse-de

Comment: base64 option hinders performance by the way. If you have the chance, you can consider sending your data with querystring.

Comment: @mehulkar Re: _"after using ajax, how do you set it as the src attribute of the img tag?"_
I have implemented something similar, loading an image using ajax.  Once my request has completed, I simply set the src of the image element to the URL using javascript and the browser (at least those I've tested) uses the image that is in cache.  
_[My purpose for using this technique was to provide a loading progress bar for the image, rather than the OP's requirement of sending specific headers.]_

Comment: duplicate here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000152/set-custom-header-for-the-request-made-from-img-tag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That facility isn't available through HTML. I would make it as an ajax request.