# get base64 by filename to view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saved name of my files into the db, and store the file in file server. So I can access the file by getting the name and do `<img src='http://localhost/upload/abc.jpg'/>` where abc is the filename. But how do I get base64? because I need to get the actual file and pass it to somewhere.

Comment: That will be server-side code, not client-side.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: try to take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124701/get-image-using-jquery-ajax-and-decode-it-to-base64/25371174#25371174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is on the same domain, you can do it with a canvas..

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}

// if the image is on the dom use this
var img = document.getElementById('img');
alert(getBase64Image(img));

// if the image isn't on the dom do this..
var img  = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    alert(getBase64Image(img));
}
img.src= "http://my/image/url.png";
```