# How to display pdf file in chrome browser in iframe tag

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a url that returns a file, but the problem is that in the Firefox browser, the file is displayed correctly, but in the Chrome and Edge browsers, it downloads instead of displaying. None of the solutions I searched for solve this problem correctly, please. guide me

```html
<iframe 
  style={style} width="100%" height="100%"
  src={`/test?letterReference=${this.props.letterReference}&fileReference=${this.props.fileReference}#toolbar=0&navbar=0`}>
</iframe>
```

Comment: [Does this answer your question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69360750/why-does-pdf-document-download-instead-of-showing-in-a-embed-iframe)

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is not useful for me @SrushtiShah

Answer (score 1):

To display a file you could also use an `<object>`:

```
<object data="{`/test?letterReference=${this.props.letterReference}&fileReference=${this.props.fileReference}#toolbar=0&navbar=0`}" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

Comment: This solution does not work because Chrome sometimes calls the address twice and causes it to be blocked @Mikelo

Comment: Does your url refers to an exact file location or to a handler which provides the file?

Comment: No, there is a controller that extracts the necessary data from the url I send and returns it @Mikelo

Comment: Ok. Could you share the header response of the url you try to display? Check if Content-Disposition is set correctly so the browser knows it has to view the file instead of download it

Comment: What should be set inside the header for Content-Disposition? @Mikelo

Comment: It should set to 'inline' to view a file, whereas 'attachment' would force download