# Is it possible to change HTTP-header of a pdf document, you want to embed in a <embed> or <iframe>?

Tags: javascript, html, http-headers, content-disposition

Refering to my other question: [Why does pdf document download instead of showing in a embed/iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69360750/why-does-pdf-document-download-instead-of-showing-in-a-embed-iframe)

When i embed a pdf document like the below examples, it downloads the documents instead of showing it embedded in the website.

```html
<embed id="showPdfDocument" src="http://example.com:8080/client/attachment/filename.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="400" height="400">
```

or

```html
<iframe id="showPdfDocument" src="http://example.com:8080/client/attachment/filename.pdf" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></iframe>
```

**My assumptions:**

- I guess i have to change the HTTP-Header of the pdf document?
- I also guess that the problem is with the field "Content-Disposition: attachment", as shown in the screenshot below

**My question:**

- How can i change the HTTP-Header of the pdf document, using html/javascript only? (Greasemonkey for example)

**Screenshot of the HTTP-Header of the pdf document:**

("Chrome Dev-Tools(F12)" -> Network Tab, select the pdf document and check the response headers)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content-disposition header triggers the save dialog. If you want to avoid it without server-side changes, try loading it via XHR and encode it as "data:" link.

Comment: I used AJAX to download pdf, and converted to base 64, and used jquery to insert the base into an <embed>. Worked perfect. Used this as explanation on how to find out how it worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787318/ajax-call-to-return-pdf-file-as-base64-string